# Доступ к папке ( не паблик ) Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображения из папки `uploads` не отображаются в шаблонах, а из папки `public` отображаются корректно

Мне надо открыть доступ к папке `storage/app/uploads`

Файл `config/filesystems.php`

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
 */

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
| reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
| will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
|
 */

'cloud'   => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
|
 */

'disks'   => [

    'local'     => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public'    => [
        'driver'     => 'local',
        'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3'        => [
        'driver'     => 's3',
        'url'        => env('AWS_URL'),
        'key'        => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret'     => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region'     => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket'     => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    'dropbox'   => [
        'driver'             => 'dropbox',
        'authorizationToken' => env('DROPBOX_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN'),
    ],
    'ftp'       => [
        'driver'   => 'ftp',
        'host'     => env('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.com'),
        'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME', 'your-username'),
        'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD', 'your-password'),

        // Optional FTP Settings...
        'port'     => env('FTP_PORT', 21),
        'root'     => env('FTP_ROOT', ''),
        'passive'  => env('FTP_PASSIVE', true),
        'ssl'      => env('FTP_SSL', true),
        'timeout'  => env('FTP_TIMEOUT', 30),
    ],
    'sftp'      => [
        'driver'   => 'sftp',
        'host'     => env('SFTP_HOST', 'example.com'),
        'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME', 'your-username'),
        'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD', 'your-password'),

        // Settings for SSH key based authentication...
        // 'privateKey' => '/path/to/privateKey',
        // 'password' => 'encryption-password',

        // Optional SFTP Settings...
        'port'     => env('SFTP_PORT', 22),
        'root'     => env('SFTP_ROOT', ''),
        'timeout'  => env('SFTP_TIMEOUT', 30),
    ],
    'rackspace' => [
        'driver'    => 'rackspace',
        'username'  => env('RACKSPACE_USERNAME', 'your-username'),
        'key'       => env('RACKSPACE_KEY', 'your-key'),
        'container' => env('RACKSPACE_CONTAINER', 'your-container'),
        'endpoint'  => 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/',
        'region'    => env('RACKSPACE_REGION', 'IAD'),
        'url_type'  => env('RACKSPACE_URL', 'publicURL'),
    ],

],

];
```

`.htaccess`

```
# Disable index view
# TODO Add in dist Options -Indexes

# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Симлинк(ярлык) storage/app/public -> public/storage/

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу Вы приготовились к сложной работе, но в ларавел все типовые задачи облегченны! Как Вы знаете у браузера доступ есть только к папке 'public', но с помощью

```
php artisan storage:link
```

можно получить доступ к папке назначенной в файле config/filesystem.php
Файл config/filesystem:

```
'disks' => [

     'public' => [
          'driver' => 'local',
          'root' => storage_path('app/public'), // доступ к папке storage/app/public
          'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
          'visibility' => 'public',
      ],
```

Если Вам надо открыть доступ к папке storage/app/uploads при использовании диска 'public', то поменяйте его в 'root' => storage_path('app/public').